Why does c delete the null character between two char arrays initialized in sequence?
I am learning c. I have the following code:
char s1[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
char s2[] = {'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};

printf("Original strings:\n\t%s\n\t%s\n", s1, s2);

Whenever I create a single char array like this, a null character is always placed at the end. So, I expect the output to be
Original strings:
    hello
    world

The output is actually
Original strings:
    helloworld
    world

It appears that the first array is initialized without a null character '\0' at the end, while the second is always initialized with a null character. The arrays are also always put right next to each other in memory (I print the address, &s1[i], along with the value stored there, s1[i]):
0x7fffe344a98e  104     'h'
0x7fffe344a98f  101     'e'
0x7fffe344a990  108     'l'
0x7fffe344a991  108     'l'
0x7fffe344a992  111     'o'
0x7fffe344a993  119     'w' - not '\0' ?
0x7fffe344a994  111     'o'
0x7fffe344a995  114     'r'
0x7fffe344a996  108     'l'
0x7fffe344a997  100     'd'
0x7fffe344a998  0       '\0'

These conditions cause that the printf function prints helloworld instead of just hello for s1 because there is no null character until after 'd'. If I delete s2, then s1 does initialize with a null character at the end and prints normally (using %s). I want to understand why c is deleting the null character after 'o' in s1 when I declare a second char array immediately after.
I can specify the size of both arrays (for instance, s1[6] = {'h', ...}), and my issue is resolved. However, I don't understand why c is deleting the null character in s1, or just never placing it in memory, when I create two char arrays sequentially in my code. Thank you.

You should probably explain why you think s1 should have a terminating `\0'.

There are no null-terminators in the arrays to begin with. Which means that when you use them ass null-terminated strings you will have undefined behavior.

you don"t have strings but just arrays of characters, which aren't null terminated. C doesn't delete 0 it just doesn't put it there. There is a zero somehow after "world" but it's by luck. You need char hello[] = "hello";

There are implicit null terminators in string literals.  Other arrays, no matter the element type, do not automatically have terminators of any kind.

As a note, to perhaps make you understand what's going on, the definition char s1[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}; is really no different from int i1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };. Do you expect the int array to have any special elements in it?

Also, there is no such thing as "char arrays initialized in sequence". Unless they are part of a struct, the compiler can place the variables anywhere it likes, and in any order.

In your question, you wrote: "Whenever I create a single char array like this, a null character is always placed at the end." -- This statement is false, as you found out yourself. In your case, the array s1 does not have a null character at the end. If you want it to have one, then I suggest that you write char s1[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}; or char s1[] = "hello"; (both are equivalent). Setting the size of the array to 6 will also work, because if the array is initialized, then all elements that are not explicitly initialilzed will be initialized to zero.

@Harrison Rankin printf("Original strings:\n\t%s\n\t%s\n", s1, s2); is undefined behavior (UB).  "%s" expects a matching pointer to a string.  s2 and s1 are both  5-byte arrays with no null characters - so they are not strings.  "The arrays are also always put right next to each other" is  false as they are not always next to each other.

Does this answer your question? Are all char arrays automatically null-terminated?

And not a dupe, but relevant: Why don't numeric arrays end with a '\0' or null character?

Another dupe: Termination character in char array

Likely you are playing with padding bytes placed after each string by the compiler, since a 64 bit compiler likes to use small arrays < 8 bytes as if they were actually numbers, since that enables all manner of optimizations.

@ShadowRanger: None of those are ideal duplicates. Only the last one is close, but it does not directly address this OP’s belief that a char array initialized by individual element values automatically has a null character appended. At least one of the answers does touch on that, but it is still not a duplicate. There must be a better one.


Whenever I create a single char array like this, a null character is always placed at the end

False.  When you do this:
char s1[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};

You're always creating an array with exactly 5 elements, populated with the 5 characters you've supplied in the initializer.  This array does not contain a null byte at the end.
If there happens to be a byte with the value 0 after this array in memory, it can appear that the array is null terminated, but it is not.  Attempting to read s1[5] is reading past the end of the array, and doing so triggers undefined behavior in your code.  This is manifesting in your case by sometimes appearing to work and sometimes not.
The above differs from this:
char s2[] = "hello";

Because a string constant always contains a terminating null byte, so the array is sized to hold the entire string which includes that terminating null.  So the array s2 above has 6 elements.

Bonus, saves a ton of characters and enhances readability.
